# Is there a shortcut in VSC jump directly to fil the quotations?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Is there a shortcut to help jump directly to the `""` instead of me having to use the mouse or arrow keys?

Here is an example of where it would be useful to jump directly to `name=""` and fill that out

`<input type="text" name="" id="">`

Comment: How did you enter the `input` tag?  And where is your cursor when you want to jump to `name=""`?  If you entered the `input` tag as `input[name]#$2` emmet will complete the tag and you can tab between the `""`'s to complete them.

Answer (score 0):

The command `ctrl+right` triggers the `cursorWordEndRight` command and let you navigate trought words.

You also can use the [Tab Out extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=albert.TabOut) to Tab out of quotes, brackets, etc for Visual Studio Code.